# Ler algo depois de uma palavra-chave C#

Tags: c#, variáveis, txt

Eu tenho a seguinte situação, tenho um documento(txt) que tem algumas coisas 'preenchidas' tipo:

```
Nome:"João"; Idade:"20"; Estado:"SC";
```

O resultado que eu queria é que as variáveis tivessem somente o que está escrito entre as aspas depois de cada palavra chave.

```
string Nome; //Receberia João

int Idade; //Receberia 20

string Estado; //Receberia SC
```

OBS: Esse documento é gerado em uma única linha por outro programa, gostaria de usar isso para preencher alguns campos automaticamente.

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de deixar esse TXT em formato JSON? Se sim, ficaria muito mais fácil com o `Newtonsoft`

Comment: Ronaldo Araújo Alves, a extensão do arquivo é .info mas todas as formas de abrir mostrar como se fosse um txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a expressão regular `[^\\s;\\\"]+\\\"[^\\\"]+\\\"` para pegar as entradas do tipo `<identificador>:<valor>`.

Separe `<identificador>` de `<valor>` com `String.Split(':');` e coloque-os em um dicionário onde a chave é `<identificador>` e o valor é `<valor>`.

Do dicionário fica mais fácil. Você pode popular variáveis, classes, vetores,... do jeito que quiser.

No [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SqueakyLameMaps)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Analisador
{
   public static Dictionary<string,string> Parse(string entrada)
   {
     Dictionary<string,string> resultado =new Dictionary<string,string>();
      MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(entrada, "[^\\s;\\\"]+\\\"[^\\\"]+\\\"");      
      foreach (Match match in matches)
      {
        string[] arr = match.Value.Split(':'); 
        resultado.Add(arr[0], arr[1].Replace("\"", ""));
      }
      return resultado;
   }

   public static void Main()
   {
      Dictionary<string,string> Valores = Parse("Nome:\"João\"; Idade:\"20\"; Estado:\"SC\";");      

      foreach(var item in Valores)
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} = {item.Value}");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Augusto Vasques, criei um projeto separado para testar seu código e funcionou perfeitamente, vou tentar implementar ele no meu projeto mas valeu mesmo pela sua ajuda:)

Comment: Consegui implementar e funcionou mas ainda não entendi muito bem essa coisa dos dicionários para esse fim, você poderia me indicar um lugar para entender melhor?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Exemplo bem simples usando o dicionário Valores : `String nome = Valores["Nome"];  Console.WriteLine("O nome é " + nome);`